# How to show "Institution" and "Location" in bibliography using unsrtdin and @thesis in bibtex file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, zotero

I am creating my bibliography by creating my `.bib` file using Zotero. I am trying to add a dissertation or any kind of thesis document respectively. Zortero creates my `.bib` just fine doing this:

```
@thesis{kafurke2019,
  title = {Auslegung Der Lichthärtenden {{Klebeverbindung}} Zwischen {{Nadel}} Und {{Galsspritze}} Für {{LED}} Basierte {{UV}}-{{Lampen}}},
  author = {Kafurke, Hanna},
  date = {2019},
  institution = {{Ostbayerische Technische Hochschule Regensburg in Kooperation mit Gerresgheimer Regensburg GmbH}},
  location = {{Regensburg/Wackersdorf, Deutschland}}
}
```

The code does contain the information about the institution and location. I would like this information to be shown in my bibliography as well. Using the `unsrtdin` bibliography style, as shown below, does not result in that.

```
\selectbiblanguage{german}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\newpage
\bibliography{Literatur}
```

Therefore my question is: How to show the `institution` and `location` in my bibliography using the `unsrtdin` bibliography style and @thesis in the `.bib` file.

Due to my universities regulations I am limited to alternatives in bibliography styles to ones that sort by order of appearance and use brackets such as "[1]" as references.

Comment: `institution` and `location` are `biblatex` names for the fields. In most BibTeX styles they are called `school` and `address`, respectively. Note also that most BibTeX styles want to see `@phdthesis` or `@mastersthesis` as type instead of the generic type `@thesis` (which is known to `biblatex`). You probably want to configure Zotero for BibTeX export and not for `biblatex` export. (Also the capitalisation in the `title` field is all over the place.)

Comment: The `unsrtdin` bibliography style does not recognize `@thesis` as a pre-defined entry type; hence, BibTeX falls back to the "catch-all" `@misc` entry type, which doesn't know what to do with the fields `institution` and `location`. (However, the `@misc` entry type does recognize the fields `organization` and `address`!) You should probably start by changing `@thesis` to either `@phdthesis` or `@mastersthesis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I had to instruct Zotero to output material in `BibTeX` instead of `BibLaTeX` format and recreate the `.bib` file. This does work by right-clicking on the project folder in Zotero and selecting the export button as well as picking `BibTeX` from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments above, the `unsrtdin` bibliography style is not programmed to recognize the `@thesis` entry type. (It does know about `@phdthesis` and `@mastersthesis, though.) As a result, BibTeX is forced to fall back on the`@misc`"catch all" entry type, which isn't set up to to process fields named`institution`,`location`, and`date`.

If you can't figure out how to instruct Zotero to output material in BibTeX instead of `biblatex` format and recreate the bib file, you'll have to manually adjust the field names `institution`, `location`, and `date` to `school`, `address`, and `year`, respectively. You should also change the entry type from `@thesis` to either `@phdthesis` or `@mastersthesis`.

While you're at it, you should also fix the cringe-inducing typos `Galsspritze` and `Gerresgheimer`. And, do also omit all double-curly-brace instances in the `title` field. (Did Zotero insert these superfluous curly braces??)

[image]

The only difference using `@mastersthesis` instead of `@phdthesis` makes is that "Diplomarbeit" is used instead of "Diss.".

Observe also that I replaced `{Regensburg/Wackersdorf}` with `{Regensburg\slash Wackersdorf}` in the bib file. This change enables LaTeX to insert a line break right after "Regensburg".

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Literatur.bib}
@phdthesis{kafurke2019,
  title  = {Auslegung der lichthärtenden Klebeverbindung zwischen Nadel und Glasspritze für LED-basierte UV-Lampen},
  author = {Kafurke, Hanna},
  year   = {2019},
  school = {Ostbayerische Technische Hochschule Regensburg in Kooperation mit Gerresheimer Regensburg GmbH},
  address= {Regensburg\slash Wackersdorf},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

\begin{document}
\cite{kafurke2019}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico and @moewe!

Indeed I had to instruct instruct Zotero to output material in BibTeX instead of biblatex format and recreate the bib file. This does work by right-clicking on the project folder and selecting the export button as well as picking BibTeX from the drop down menu.

Mico thank you for pointing out the typos!

Mico Yes, Zotero insertet the double-curly-braces and also capitalises every word in the title. I do not know yet how to fix this.

Comment: The double-curly-braces are there because the title is in Title Case in Zotero, where it should be sentence case. If you change the title to sentence case in Zotero (right-click the title, sentence-case), the double-braces will go away. Alternately, you can disable them with a preference change, but because Zotero expects titles to be sentence-cased, the exporter must by default assume that capitalized words are proper nouns, and need protection on export. It's all laid out in the BBT FAQ: https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/support/faq/ .

Comment: Is `\slash ` always preferable to `/`?

Comment: Why the downvote? What did I do wrong?

Comment: @retorquere - I wouldn’t say it’s **always** preferable. For instance, if wouldn’t use it for pairs of very short words such as `and/or`.

Comment: But could it be harmful there?

Comment: @retorquere - I'm not sure how I should think about "harmful" in this context. To me, allowing a line break between `and/` and `or`, or between `yes/` and `no`, would seem to be more than just a bit unfortunate. I guess I'd start to say the benefits of using `\slash` instead of `/` outweigh the minor costs once you start dealing with slightly longer word pairs, such as `north/south`, `happy/sad`, and `left/right`.

Comment: Alright, thanks.